# wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In my quiz i have created a questions table with numbers it is used for whether the question is answered or not. if it answered the visited column in answer table goes to 1 or else 0
as

```
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+---------+
| id | answer | questions_id | user_id | exam_group_id | modules_id | marks | visited |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+---------+
|  1 | ans2   |            8 |       3 |             1 |          1 |     0 |       1 |
|  2 | NULL   |            9 |       3 |             1 |          1 |     0 |       0 |
|  3 | NULL   |            6 |       3 |             1 |          1 |     0 |       0 |
|  4 | ans1   |            5 |       3 |             1 |          2 |     1 |       1 |
|  5 | NULL   |            4 |       3 |             1 |          2 |     0 |       0 |
|  6 | NULL   |            3 |       3 |             1 |          2 |     0 |       0 |
+----+--------+--------------+---------+---------------+------------+-------+---------+
```

and i checked the questions based on visited in my view page as like

```
<% @slno = 0 %>
  <ul class="student_list">
    <% @questions.each do |s| %>
    <% @slno = @slno + 1 %>
      <% if ((Answer.find_by_sql["SELECT visited from answers where questions_id=#{s.id}"]) == 1) %>
        <li class="student_names">
          <a href="#" id="<%=s.id%>"  class="student-link" > <%= @slno %></a>
        </li>
        <% else %>
        <li class="student_names2">
          <a href="#" id="<%=s.id%>"  class="student-link2" > <%= @slno %></a>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

but it gives the error as **wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)**

Comment: what line do you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer.find_by_sql is wrong! Use space before [] or `()`

```
<% @slno = 0 %>
<ul class="student_list">
  <% @questions.each do |s| %>
  <% @slno = @slno + 1 %>
    <% if ((Answer.find_by_sql(["SELECT visited from answers where questions_id=#{s.id}"])) == 1) %>
      <li class="student_names">
        <a href="#" id="<%=s.id%>"  class="student-link" > <%= @slno %></a>
      </li>
      <% else %>
      <li class="student_names2">
        <a href="#" id="<%=s.id%>"  class="student-link2" > <%= @slno %></a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And you don't need to use `@slno` - use `each_with_index`

refactored code:

```
<ul class="student_list">
  <% @questions.each_with_index do |s, index| %>
    <% if ((Answer.find_by_sql(["SELECT visited from answers where questions_id=#{s.id}"])) == 1) %>
      <li class="student_names">
        <a href="#" id="<%=s.id%>"  class="student-link" > <%= index %></a>
      </li>
    <% else %>
      <li class="student_names2">
        <a href="#" id="<%=s.id%>"  class="student-link2" > <%= index %></a>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: please pay attention on @Supremacy answer. It suggests a good improvement - to use method `where` instead of raw SQL

Comment: i tried it does not works when we use index it returns from 0 right

Comment: possible problem is in incorrect column name. your variant should be `Answer.where(questions_id: s.id).count == 1` (you have `questions_id` not `question_id`) or even simpler `Answer.where(questions_id: s.id).any?`

Comment: additional note: maybe I did not catch your if-conditions. it confuses me because you select column `visited` from table where `questions_id = :id` and compare the result with 1. I do not understand how it works and I am not sure if it really works. In my console I get Array of objects and if I start to compare it with 1 I always get false. Please review/recheck your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your find_by_sql in () like so:

```
Answer.find_by_sql(["SELECT visited from answers where questions_id=#{s.id}"])
```

you also don't need to write your own SQL in this instance, instead you can simply do this:

```
<% if Answer.where(questions_id: s.id).count == 1 %>
```